# Hiding rows based on cell value is very slow

Tags: excel, vba, row, hide

I have working code to hide/unhide rows depending on the corresponding cell value.

This is a list of materials and there is a 'finalize' button. You press the button and any row where quantity = 0 should be hidden.

There are 400+ lines and I can see the lines disappear. It is processing roughly 20 lines per second which makes it over 20 seconds to do the list. The list will double every few months.

Is there another method that will hide the lines faster?

**Hide:**

```vb
Public Sub HideRows()
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("H18:H469")
    cell.EntireRow.Hidden = (cell.Value = 0 And cell.Value <> "")
Next cell
End Sub
```

**Unhide:**

```vb
Public Sub UnhideRows()
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("H18:H469")
    If (cell.Value = 0 And cell.Value <> "") Then cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: turn off screen updating at the start of your code `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`. Be sure to turn if back on at the end of your code

Comment: This is one of those times where we recommend that you build up a range of cells you want to hide and then hide that range all at once

Comment: Why the double test? cell.Value = 0 And cell.Value <> ""   Rather than just =0 ?

Comment: But I also don't understand this bit of logic you use `cell.Value = 0 And cell.Value <> ""` This can never be true, so I'm not sure I understand the purpose. Maybe you mean `Or` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was just typing up as appeared in comments. Use Union to gather qualifying ranges and hide in one go. I am not sure why you are doing a double test. Wouldn't = 0 be sufficient? Or as @Marcucciby2 queries, did you intend an Or?

And as mentioned in other answer, you can do some optimization by switching of things like ScreenUpdating, pageBreaks and switch to manual calculation mode.

If possible, get rid of that ActiveSheet reference and use the actual workbook and worksheet references.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub HideRows()
    Dim cell As Range, unionRng As Range
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("H18:H469")
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
            If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, cell)
            Else
                Set unionRng = cell
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I forgot to add that I am no VBA wizard and I took the majority of the functions I use off the internet from the great people like yourselves ;-)

Can I please also have the script to UN-hide (i.e. display everything back)?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Judt copy the code insde the sub into a new sub (change the name) and change this line: _If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True_  to _If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.EntireRow.Hidden = False_

Comment: That make sense?

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @QHarr it does not unhide the hidden rows.

Comment: @JansenMalaggay It did for the OP so perhaps something is different in your set-up?

Comment: @QHarr Thanks for your idea, I just added a little bit of code block to unhide the hidden rows first before running your code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Turn off screen updating and manual calculations at the start of your code. Be sure to turn if back on at the end of your code.

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    '...your code...
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```