# how can I speed up loops

Tags: excel, vba, performance, loops

It runs just fine but the execution is slower than I would like and i'm not sure why. I have another segment of code that reverses this as well...

There are only 5 sheets that it looping through, and only in a given range ta boot. It is only checking for a null value in column A and if it is null then the row hides.

I've tried turning off calculations, events, and screen updates, but it still isn't fast... Am I missing a memory drain somewhere in this??? It acts like it wants to crash, but then continues...

```
    Sub HideBlanks()
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    For Each Sheet In Worksheets
        If Sheet.Index > 1 Then
            With Sheet
                For r = 4 To 350
                    With activesheets
                        If Range("A" & r) = "" Then
                            Range("A" & r).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        End If
                    End With
                Next r
            End With
        End If
        Range("a1").Select
    Next Sheet

    Worksheets(1).Activate

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    End Sub
```

Maybe I am going about this the wrong way completely...

End goal is to hide (or prevent) the blank cells between A4:G350 from printing those rows if the value is "".

Comment: get rid of `Sheet.Activate` and change the With to `With Sheet`

Comment: Then use Union to create a range of the cells to hide and hide once outside the loop per sheet.

Comment: Can you explain union please Scott?

Comment: [`Application.Union`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union)

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply this... I have one argument, basically is A null... next row.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53121616/vba-excel-hiding-rows-based-on-cell-value-is-very-slow

Comment: How can your code even run with `With activesheets` and no dots anyway so you are only ever referring to a single sheet?

Comment: @SJR no, it loops. If i remove the With Activesheets it ignores the loop and only impacts the active sheet... why I'm not sure...

Comment: We have entered the Twilight Zone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May Try

```
 Sub HideBlanks()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rw As Long
    Dim Arr As Variant, Rng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Ws.Index > 1 Then
        Arr = Ws.Range("A4:A350").Value
          For Rw = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
            If Arr(Rw, 1) = "" Then
                If Rng Is Nothing Then
                Set Rng = Ws.Range("A" & Rw + 3)
                Else
                Set Rng = Union(Rng, Ws.Range("A" & Rw + 3))
                End If
             End If
            Next Rw
        End If
   If Not Rng Is Nothing Then Rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
   Set Rng = Nothing
   Next Ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    End Sub
```

Comment: That is exactly it!!! Now could I be a pain and in the idea of being studious, could you please explain explain a little in how the code works a little... I understand most of it but `Set Rng = Union(Rng, Ws.Range("A" & Rw + 3))` and `If Not Rng Is Nothing Then Rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True` are kind of throwing me for a loop.

Comment: Welcome @Roy. 1st is the syntax for adding more rnages in a union of ranges. 2nd is to check if no blank cells are encountered  and the Rng is empty.

Comment: Thank you! Why is it set as 'if not rng is nothing'? That seems counterintuitive to me...

Comment: attempt to hide `EntireRow` with empty `Rng` will raise error 91

Comment: The opposite of something is nothing @DanielRoy