# Slow VBA loop for hiding rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops, hide

Following code used to loop through all rows in a range and hide them based on cell value in that cell, and one below. If both cell values = "" then intent is to hide entire row. All works fine but is terribly slow. Any advice on something faster would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sheets("Morning Report Export Sheet").Activate

For x = 10 To 108
    If Cells(x, 9).Value = "" Then
        If Cells(x + 1, 9).Value = "" Then
            Cells(x, 9).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
Next
```

... Have also tried the following, but just as slow...

```
If Cells(x, 9).Value = "" And Cells(x + 1, 9).Value = "" Then
```

Comment: It would be much faster to pull the 9th column's range into a variant array (you'll have to transpose it into a single-dimensional array), and then iterate this array's values, and when the conditions are met you `Union` the corresponding `Range` into an in-memory range of cells (note: loop does nothing other than building a union'ed range object with all the relevant cells); after the loop you then go `theUnionRange.EntireRow.Hidden = True` and poof you've just hidden all rows that needed to be hidden in a single operation, reading from the sheet *once*, and writing to the sheet *once*.

Comment: Or you could mask the problem and keep continuously hitting the worksheet anyway by turning off `Application.ScreenUpdating` before the loop and turning it back on after the loop, but I bet it wouldn't even be needed if you go with the `Union` approach.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53121616/hiding-rows-based-on-cell-value-is-very-slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote up both versions because I am bored.

This is the array method mentioned by @MathieuGuindon

```vb
Sub HideRowsUsingArrays()
    Dim x As Long, HideRows As Range
    Dim StartRow As Long, EndRow As Long, Col As Long
    
    'TARGET RANGE
    Col = 9
    StartRow = 10
    EndRow = 108
    'TARGET RANGE
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = Sheets("Morning Report Export Sheet")
    
    Dim vArr() As Variant
    'Saving all values in the target range to an array
    vArr = sh.Cells(StartRow, Col).Resize(EndRow).Value
    
    'Looping through the array
    For x = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr) - 1
        'If val or next val is empty
        If vArr(x) = "" And vArr(x + 1) = "" Then
            'Add the corresponding row to HideRows range
            'Union causes an error if HideRows is nothing, so the first iteration cant use Union
            If HideRows Is Nothing Then
                Set HideRows = sh.Rows(x + StartRow - 1).EntireRow
            Else
                Set HideRows = Union(HideRows, sh.Rows(x + StartRow - 1).EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next x
    
    'Hide the gathered rows
    If Not HideRows Is Nothing Then HideRows.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

This is the Range method linked to by @TimWilliams

```vb
Sub HideRowsUsingRanges()
    Dim cell As Range, HideRows As Range
    Dim StartRow As Long, EndRow As Long, Col As Long
    
    'TARGET RANGE
    Col = 9
    StartRow = 10
    EndRow = 108
    'TARGET RANGE
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = Sheets("Morning Report Export Sheet")
    
    Dim r As Range
    'Saving the target range
    set r = sh.Cells(StartRow, Col).Resize(EndRow)
    
    'Looping through each cell of the range
    For Each cell In r
        'If val or next val is empty
        If cell.Value = "" And cell.Offset(1).Value = "" Then
            'Add the corresponding row to HideRows range
            'Union causes an error if HideRows is nothing, so the first iteration cant use Union
            If HideRows Is Nothing Then
                Set HideRows = cell
            Else
                Set HideRows = Union(HideRows, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    
    'Hide the gathered rows
    If Not HideRows Is Nothing Then HideRows.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Bottom option worked significantly quicker, thank you. Top one failed to run and was out of Range on line: `If vArr(x).Value = "" And vArr(x + 1).Value = "" Then`

Comment: Oh whoops, those `.Value`s shouldnt be there. I'll remove them