# Excel macro "Entirerow.Hidden" How to make it run faster?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a module in a bigger workbook that search for "N/A" (not available) in cell range “B6-B125” and hide the entire row if so. Plus, it changes the name of the worksheet according to cell "D1". But it runs slow. And because I have another module running this module in multiple sheets, it needs to be faster. Does anyone have a suggestion for that?

```
 Sub Update_Kitchen()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
        ThisWorkbook.Unprotect "7300"
        
            Set Target = Range("D1")
            If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
            Application.ActiveSheet.Name = VBA.Left(Target, 31)
            
        ThisWorkbook.Protect "7300"
         

Dim xRg As Range
   
        
        For Each xRg In Range("B6:B125")
            If xRg.Value = "N/A" Then
                xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = True
         
            Else
                xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                xRg.EntireRow.AutoFit
               
            End If
        Next xRg
    
    Range("K4").Value = DateTime.Now
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Unhide all rows, then loop and create a range to be hidden using `Union`, then hide *once* at the end.

Comment: Here's [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67780629/14608750) on a previous question.