# Fastest way to Hide empty rows from Cell Range using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I had this code to hide an entire row if the range of cells are empty. It works fine but the problem is, it takes to long to show the result.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
Dim xRg As Range
    For Each xRg In Range("D22:D728")
        If xRg.Value = "" Then
            xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = True
     
        Else
            xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next xRg
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53121616/hiding-rows-based-on-cell-value-is-very-slow

Comment: @TimWilliams but how will i do it with my code? It only Hides but not to unhide rows that has contents

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
Range("D22:D728").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to my question. Thank you for sharing your codes. just added some work around from this site.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
Range("D22:D728").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Dim cell As Range, unionRng As Range
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("D22:D728")
    If cell.Value = 0 Then
        If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
            Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, cell)
        Else
            Set unionRng = cell
        End If
    End If
Next
If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try screen updating:

```
Sub Stop_ScreenUpdate ()
Application.ScreenUpdating = false
" your code "
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Try Screen Updating

Comment: you can edit your answer with additional details, rather than adding those details as a comment. This is preferred as comment can eventually be consolidated and many people won't see all of them. I went ahead and made this edit for you.